# How to find the Median per GROUP (where the GROUP BY has multiple column conditions)

Tags: mysql, median

I've encountered a bunch of similar pages which find the [median of the column](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median) and [median per group](https://technicalmarketing.guide/blog/how-to-calculate-the-median-per-group-with-mysql/) but never median per `group by` where there are multiple conditions.

How can I do this?

Here is an example of the dataset I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE trans
    (`order_entry_date` datetime, `brand` varchar(2), `customer_id` int, `webshop_order_number` int, `store_country` varchar(2), `product_id` bigint, `units_ordered` int, `gross_order_entry` int, `net_order_entry` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO trans
    (`order_entry_date`, `brand`, `customer_id`, `webshop_order_number`, `store_country`, `product_id`, `units_ordered`, `gross_order_entry`, `net_order_entry`)
VALUES
    ('2020-03-23 00:00:00', 'aa', 304044, 700112, 'ds', 8719852058986, 1, 41.24, 41.24),
    ('2020-03-23 00:00:00', 'aa', 304041, 700112, 'ds', 8719852051230, 1, 61.12, 84.22),
    ('2020-03-23 00:00:00', 'js', 304041, 700112, 'jp', 8719852051230, 2, 61.12, 84.22),
    ('2019-03-23 00:00:00', 'js', 302012, 700112, 'th', 8719852058770, 2, 61.88, 51.66),
    ('2019-03-23 00:00:00', 'TH', 302011, 700112, 'th', 8719852058770, 3, 61.88, 51.66),
    ('2020-03-23 00:00:00', 'TH', 304040, 700112, 'DE', 8719852051230, 1, 61.12, 84.22)
;
```

Comment: and which are the multiple conditions?

Comment: Which version of MySql do you use? Version 8 has windowing functions which make this task easier.

Comment: for mysql 8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621343/mysql-calculating-median-of-values-grouped-by-a-column  for mysql 5,7 and below https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158383/190821

Comment: Im using MYSQL 5.6 and I need to group by the order_entry_date,brand,store_country. From my understanding the thread solution that nbk showed only works for a single group by condition ( or at least I do not know how to translate that to accept multiple group by conditions)

Comment: I want to further clarify that this is the code I'm working with so far ; 


SELECT
YEAR(order_entry_date) AS _year,
brand, 
store_country AS country,
AVG(units_ordered) AS average_buy_freq,
avg(Marks) as median_val
(
(COUNT(CASE WHEN (units_ordered >  1) THEN 1 ELSE null END)/
 COUNT(customer_id)) * 100 
) as multi_time_perc
FROM trans
GROUP BY brand,country,_year
ORDER BY _year DESC; 

.

As you can see, solutions which use an additional where clause (outer query) would interfere with my other required columns, so that's also another limitation im dealing with